Assign * to database schema on Sql
I have created a schema. I need this schema to be accessible to all currently users and new users that will be created in the future. The only queries i find on the internet is this GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: [MySchema] TO [userhere]

It would be helpful to mention the database management system (server) being used.


to be accessible to all currently users and new users that will be
created in the future

You should give the desired access to public role:
INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: [MySchema] TO public


thanks, i cant accept this as an answer since i have less than 15 reputation.

@Nelani You might not be able to upvote, but there's no limits for accepting the answer (clicking the checkmark). Note also, it is possible for someone to have access to a database instance without being in the public role. They would be missed in such a case. But it's a very unlikely scenario since the default for new users is to be in the public role.

@J.D. can you please provide any example of how to drop user from public role?

@sepupic You can't drop a user from the public role of a database they're mapped to. But a Login that can access the database instance, doesn't have to be mapped to the database to begin with. That's probably clearer terminology than what I previously stated. Also, a Login can be unmapped but still access said database even, should they be in the SysAdmin server role. But that would be a moot point here since they would then implicitly have access to the user created schema anyway.

@J.D. Do you want to say that  any member of sysadmin server role CAN not be a menber of public database role? I insist that it will be, and it cannot be changed

@sepupic No, that is not what I said. Sure, you can map a User for a Login who is in the server SysAdmin role to a database and that User will be in the public database role. But if you never map a User for that Login to said database, then that User won't exist in that database to be explicitly provisioned into the public database role. That User object just doesn't exist at that point. As I said, that case is a moot point regardless, since someone in the server SysAdmin role will implicitly have access to the database anyway.

@J.D. I'm sysadmin and I never was mapped to any database as a "user", if I make select user I'm dbo as every sysadmin is mapped to dbo. And if I execute select is_rolemember('public'), sure I get 1, so when I asked you any example of how it can be that user has access to a database but is not a member of public role it is because it just cannot be any situation when you access a database but not a member of public role.

@J.D. And when you are not a member of sysadmin role, you are not mapped to tempdb or master databases, but you still access them as guest user, try to execute select is_rolemember('public') in the context of these databases, you'll get 1

@sepupic That's good to know about how those user mappings work, thanks. My original point still stands, "it is possible for someone to have access to a database instance without being in the public [database] role.". If someone isn't mapped to the database in question, and isn't in the SysAdmin server role (which again would've been a moot point anyway), then they wouldn't be in the public role of the user created database they are not mapped to. In such a case, that person wouldn't have access to the user created schema that OP made (obviously).

@J.D. I just don't know how else can I explain you that you cannot access any database without being a member of public role. I give you examples that prove what I said and you still did not give any valid example  that shows what you said

@sepupic I think you're just confused on what I'm saying, no biggie though. I highlighted the word instance to try to make it clearer. Here's a simple way to demonstrate what I'm saying: 1. Create a new schema (in a non-system database). 2. Create a new Login. 3. Log into your instance with that Login. 4. Try to access that schema in that database and you'll get an error (along the lines of the user being unable to access that database). Yet you're still able to access your instance as that Login - because you are evidently logged in.
